# .cmd Batch file not pushing my local .git repo to GitHub

Tags: windows, git, batch-file, github, cmd

I have this 'gittify.cmd' batch file in my working directory:

```
git status
git add --all
git status
set /p commitComment=Enter the Commit Comment:%=%
@echo git commit -m "%commitComment%"
git status
git push origin master
```

The problem is that it's not pushing the changes to GitHub... But if I type in by hand, command by command, it works without problem.

This is the last commands after "git push origin master":

```
C:\www\lantosistvan.com>git push origin master
github --credentials get: github: command not found
Username for 'https://github.com': <My username>
Password for 'https://<My username>@github.com':
github --credentials store: github: command not found
Everything up-to-date
```

After this, I need to delete from local .git the particular file with this command:

```
git reset HEAD <stucked file>
```

**UPDATE 1:**

This is in my PATH:

```
C:\Users\<My username>\AppData\Local\GitHub\PortableGit_<code>\bin
```

I can run git in cmd and ConEmu without problem.

```
git config --global credential.helper
```

not showing anything.

I not use SSH when I pushing to GitHub. I always type in my Username and Pass.

**UPDATE 2:**

On my computer, GitHub and Git Bash installed in the same time. PATH only directed to GitHub folder under AppData.

**UPDATE 3 - SOLUTION:**

For some reason, @echo caused the error. it's just simple blocks somehow the commiting. So before git push origin master, my working directory wasn't clean. Removing @echo solves the problem:

```
git status
git add --all
git status
set /p commitComment=Enter the Commit Comment:%=%
git commit -m "%commitComment%"
git status
git push origin master
```

Comment: I suggest using git-gui or GitExtensions as a commit tool and actually inspect what you are about to commit to avoid accidentally committing bits of left over rubbish and files you didn't mean to include. I would also suggest not pushing every commit. Instead, push once the task is complete. A task may require a number of discrete units of work that should be separate commits.

Comment: I already excluded the node_modules folder and some other files that I don't need to push in a .gitignore file. Thanks the info, I will look after a plugin for Sublime Text or Gulp, which is pushing only a modified file imediately.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have a *credential helper* configured for Git, and there seems to be a problem with calling it locally.

Can you do the following: Check which credential helper is installed by running

```
git config --global credential.helper
```

This should print the credential helper executable's name and path. Verify that this file is installed locally and is included in your shell's path.

From the message, it looks like the `github` executable is not on your `PATH`. Try to fix that and then run the batch file again.